# Find Parent Recursively using Query

Tags: postgresql, recursive-query

I am using postgresql. I have the table as like below

```
parent_id    child_id
----------------------
101       102
103       104
104       105
105       106
```

I want to write a sql query which will give the final parent of input.

i.e suppose i pass 106 as input then , its output will be 103.

```
(106 --> 105 --> 104 --> 103)
```

Comment: If You are using postgres, remove sql-server and oracle tags.Please.

Comment: linq-to-sql doesn't support postgresql, so removed that tag too.

Answer (score 76):

Here's a complete example. First the `DDL`:

```
test=> CREATE TABLE node (
test(>   id SERIAL,
test(>   label TEXT NOT NULL, -- name of the node
test(>   parent_id INT,
test(>   PRIMARY KEY(id)
test(> );
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "node_id_seq" for serial column "node.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "node_pkey" for table "node"
CREATE TABLE
```

...and some data...

```
test=> INSERT INTO node (label, parent_id) VALUES ('n1',NULL),('n2',1),('n3',2),('n4',3);
INSERT 0 4
test=> INSERT INTO node (label) VALUES ('garbage1'),('garbage2'), ('garbage3');
INSERT 0 3
test=> INSERT INTO node (label,parent_id) VALUES ('garbage4',6);
INSERT 0 1
test=> SELECT * FROM node;
id |  label   | parent_id 
----+----------+-----------
 1 | n1       |          
 2 | n2       |         1
 3 | n3       |         2
 4 | n4       |         3
 5 | garbage1 |          
 6 | garbage2 |          
 7 | garbage3 |          
 8 | garbage4 |         6
(8 rows)
```

This performs a recursive query on every id in node:

```
test=> WITH RECURSIVE nodes_cte(id, label, parent_id, depth, path) AS (
 SELECT tn.id, tn.label, tn.parent_id, 1::INT AS depth, tn.id::TEXT AS path 
 FROM node AS tn 
 WHERE tn.parent_id IS NULL
UNION ALL
 SELECT c.id, c.label, c.parent_id, p.depth + 1 AS depth, 
        (p.path || '->' || c.id::TEXT) 
 FROM nodes_cte AS p, node AS c 
 WHERE c.parent_id = p.id
)
SELECT * FROM nodes_cte AS n ORDER BY n.id ASC;
id |  label   | parent_id | depth |    path    
----+----------+-----------+-------+------------
 1 | n1       |           |     1 | 1
 2 | n2       |         1 |     2 | 1->2
 3 | n3       |         2 |     3 | 1->2->3
 4 | n4       |         3 |     4 | 1->2->3->4
 5 | garbage1 |           |     1 | 5
 6 | garbage2 |           |     1 | 6
 7 | garbage3 |           |     1 | 7
 8 | garbage4 |         6 |     2 | 6->8
(8 rows)
```

This gets all of the descendents WHERE node.id = 1:

```
test=> WITH RECURSIVE nodes_cte(id, label, parent_id, depth, path) AS (
 SELECT tn.id, tn.label, tn.parent_id, 1::INT AS depth, tn.id::TEXT AS path FROM node AS tn WHERE tn.id = 1
UNION ALL                   
 SELECT c.id, c.label, c.parent_id, p.depth + 1 AS depth, (p.path || '->' || c.id::TEXT) FROM nodes_cte AS p, node AS c WHERE c.parent_id = p.id
)                                                                
SELECT * FROM nodes_cte AS n;
id | label | parent_id | depth |    path    
----+-------+-----------+-------+------------
 1 | n1    |           |     1 | 1
 2 | n2    |         1 |     2 | 1->2
 3 | n3    |         2 |     3 | 1->2->3
 4 | n4    |         3 |     4 | 1->2->3->4
(4 rows)
```

The following will get the path of the node with id 4:

```
test=> WITH RECURSIVE nodes_cte(id, label, parent_id, depth, path) AS (
 SELECT tn.id, tn.label, tn.parent_id, 1::INT AS depth, tn.id::TEXT AS path 
 FROM node AS tn 
 WHERE tn.parent_id IS NULL
UNION ALL
 SELECT c.id, c.label, c.parent_id, p.depth + 1 AS depth, 
        (p.path || '->' || c.id::TEXT) 
 FROM nodes_cte AS p, node AS c 
 WHERE c.parent_id = p.id
)
SELECT * FROM nodes_cte AS n WHERE n.id = 4;
id | label | parent_id | depth |    path    
----+-------+-----------+-------+------------
 4 | n4    |         3 |     4 | 1->2->3->4
(1 row)
```

And let's assume you want to limit your search to descendants with a `depth` less than three (note that `depth` hasn't been incremented yet):

```
test=> WITH RECURSIVE nodes_cte(id, label, parent_id, depth, path) AS (
  SELECT tn.id, tn.label, tn.parent_id, 1::INT AS depth, tn.id::TEXT AS path 
  FROM node AS tn WHERE tn.id = 1
UNION ALL
  SELECT c.id, c.label, c.parent_id, p.depth + 1 AS depth, 
         (p.path || '->' || c.id::TEXT) 
  FROM nodes_cte AS p, node AS c 
  WHERE c.parent_id = p.id AND p.depth < 2
)
SELECT * FROM nodes_cte AS n;
 id | label | parent_id | depth | path 
----+-------+-----------+-------+------
  1 | n1    |           |     1 | 1
  2 | n2    |         1 |     2 | 1->2
(2 rows)
```

I'd recommend using an `ARRAY` data type instead of a string for demonstrating the "path", but the arrow is more illustrative of the parent<=>child relationship.

Comment: is possible this method in self many to many? Imagine there's nodes which has many parents but there's a field something like subtree_id, to say node A is child of B just in this sub tree, if node B is in another subtree but A is not in that, don't show A under B. I hope i said my purpose!

Comment: How to ger all parents from last chield?

Answer (score 25):

Use [`WITH RECURSIVE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) to create a Common Table Expression (CTE).  For the non-recursive term, get the rows in which the child is immediately below the parent:

```
SELECT
   c.child_id,
   c.parent_id
FROM
   mytable c
LEFT JOIN
   mytable p ON c.parent_id = p.child_id
WHERE
   p.child_id IS NULL

 child_id | parent_id
----------+-----------
      102 |       101
      104 |       103
```

For the recursive term, you want the children of these children.

```
WITH RECURSIVE tree(child, root) AS (
   SELECT
      c.child_id,
      c.parent_id
   FROM
      mytable c
   LEFT JOIN
      mytable p ON c.parent_id = p.child_id
   WHERE
      p.child_id IS NULL
   UNION
   SELECT
      child_id,
      root
   FROM
      tree
   INNER JOIN
      mytable on tree.child = mytable.parent_id
)
SELECT * FROM tree;

 child | root
-------+------
   102 |  101
   104 |  103
   105 |  103
   106 |  103
```

You can filter the children when querying the CTE:

```
WITH RECURSIVE tree(child, root) AS (...) SELECT root FROM tree WHERE child = 106;

 root
------
  103
```

Comment: This is really elegant. It seems like the ideal teaching example for a recursive CTE. Because of that, it was easy to modify for my use case.