# SQL queries optimization - postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Am a beginner in SQL. How can I optimize this query

```
select * from t1 where parent_id in (select id from t1 where id= 'X')

UNION

select * from t1 where parent_id in (select id from  t1 where parent_id in (select id from t1 where id= 'X'))
UNION

select * from t1 where parent_id in (select id from t1 where parent_id in (select id from  t1 where parent_id in (select id from t1 where id= 'X')))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find Parent Recursively using Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699395/find-parent-recursively-using-query)

Answer (score 1):

You can try with recursive cte:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
  select * from t1 where t1.id='X'
  union all
  select t1.*
  from cte c
    join t1
      on t1.id=c.parent_id
)
select distinct * from cte
```