# Postgresql How to get all parents (tracking) from child

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I got something like this table:

```
id  | code    | code_parent | 
----|---------|------------ |
 1  | 1       |   1         | 
 2  | 2       |   2         | 
 3  | 3       |   1         | 
 4  | 4       |   3         |  
 5  | 5       |   2         | 
 6  | 6       |   4         | 
 7  | 7       |   6         |
```

I want to return a list with all the parents. Example:

```
select * from table where code 7
```

I would like the return like this:

```
{1,3,4,6}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find Parent Recursively using Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699395/find-parent-recursively-using-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select code_parent, 1 as lev
      from t
      where code = 7
      union all
      select t.code_parent, lev + 1
      from cte join
           t
           on cte.code_parent = t.code
      where t.code <> t.code_parent
     )
select code_parent as code
from cte;
```

If you want an array:

```
select array_agg(code_parent)
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=bd63308c00250146aa115b6bc33d8aae) is a db<>fiddle.