# self join how to reference the association from parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have `Category` class shown below

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subcategories, class_name: "Category", foreign_key: "parent_category_id"
  belongs_to :parent_category, class_name: "Category"

  belongs_to :main_category
end
```

and I wonder if I can define `main_category` association the rails way that I can
reference the `#main_category` on subcategories but leaving the `main_category_id` empty (as the reference on `subcategory#main_category_id` will duplicate the data which is in `parent_category#main_category_id` or it is just premature optimization? ).

```
category = Category.new main_category: main_category
subcategory = Category.new parent_category: category

assert_equal category.main_category, subcategory.main_category
```

Comment: The phrase is "Premature optimization". And yes this does add duplication to your tables and you would have to use callbacks or triggers to ensure that the `main_category_id` column is actually filled.

Comment: thanks for correction :) 
I asked the question to get know if there is a rails way of defining that association without that duplication of #main_category_id on subcategory

Answer (score 1):

you can create a proxy that subcategories will delegate `main_category` to parent, the drawback that there're 3 queries to get `main_category`

```rb
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :subcategories, class_name: "Category", foreign_key: "parent_category_id"
 belongs_to :parent_category, class_name: "Category"

 belongs_to :main_category, class_name: "Category"

 # with subcategories, there're 3 queries: 
 # super return nil -> find parent_category -> find main_category of the parent 
 def main_category
   super || parent_category&.main_category
 end
end
```

Comment: You can use `Category.eager_load(parent_catgory:  :parent_category)` to force a single query.

Comment: Yes, I thought about that, but wished there is rails way  thx @max for `eager_load`

Comment: Sidenote: `belongs_to` is enforced by default as of rails 5 so for the `super` call to return `nil` the association would need to be  `belongs_to :main_category, class_name: "Category", optional: true` (same applies for `parent_category` with the safe nav)

Answer (score 1):

You can use indirect assocations to setup "short-cuts" through the tree.

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Going up...
  has_many :subcategories, 
     class_name: "Category", 
     foreign_key: "parent_category_id"
  has_many :grand_child_categories, 
     class_name: "Category", 
     through: :subcategories
  has_many :great_grand_child_categories, 
     class_name: "Category", 
     through: :grand_child_categories

  # Going down...
  belongs_to :parent_category, 
    class_name: "Category"
  has_one :grand_parent_category, 
    through: :parent_category,
    class_name: "Category"
  has_one :great_grand_parent_category, 
    through: :grand_parent_category,
    class_name: "Category"
end
```

However if you have a heirarchy of unlimited depth ActiveRecord::Assocations can't really solve the problem of finding the node at the bottom of the tree. That requires more advanced SQL like a [recursive common table expression (CTE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699395/find-parent-recursively-using-query).

While ActiveRecord does has the basic tools for creating self joining assocations most of the more andvaced stuff is out of scope and can be handled with gems like Ancestry.